# How to get the command history only for the current shell process?

Tags: bash, command-history

In a bash shell, when I run `history`, it provides the history of all the commands not only those typed in the current shell, but also those in the previous shells. How can I get the history of the commands only typed in the current shell so far? This is useful when you want to find a command  that you know has been typed in the current shell. Thanks.

Comment: No Tim, that is not possible with a simple bash history. To do that you would need the PID of the bash executing the command (at least). [This show a way to get a permanent history](http://jesrui.sdf-eu.org/remember-all-your-bash-history-forever.html), but that doesn't work with a vanilla bash history.

Answer (score 5):

Provided that [histappend](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6501/31256) is not set and no games are played with [PROMPT_COMMAND](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1288/31256), the [history](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-History-Builtins) command can:

```
  -a   Append the ``new'' history lines (history lines entered 
       since the beginning of the current bash session) to 
       the history file.
```

If we want to leave our *real* history file unharmed, we could do:

```
$ cat .bash_history
#1482030925
ls
#1482030926
date
#1482030928
free

$ echo "one more command"
one more command

$ echo "another command"
another command

$ HISTFILE=foo history -a
$ cat foo
#1482031879
cat .bash_history
#1482031887
echo "one more command"
#1482031892
echo "another command"
#1482031899
HISTFILE=foo history -a
```

The previous commands from earlier sessions (ls, date, free) do not show up in our "new" history file, `foo` - I hope the example brings across that point.

Another approach would be to save the current history file (at the beginning of the login session!) and then later append the current session's history to the history file (either by running "history -a" or by logging out) and then compare both files:

```
$ history > hist.backup

$ echo "a new command"
a new command
$ echo "one more command"
one more command

$ history > hist.current 
$ diff hist.{backup,current}
4a5,7
>     5  2016-12-17 19:38:57 echo "a new command"
>     6  2016-12-17 19:39:01 echo "one more command"
>     7  2016-12-17 19:39:07 history > hist.current
```

Note: I'm a huge fan of setting `HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '` (introduced in bash 3, IIRC), [timestamps](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-HISTTIMEFORMAT) help a lot to find out when a command was executed.

Answer (score 2):

Use `comm` to compare the entire history (incl. current Bash session) with the already persisted history in `.bash_history` and only print those lines that are unique to the current session -- which should show only those commands that were executed since starting the current Bash shell

```
comm --nocheck-order -23 <( history | cut -c 8- ) ~/.bash_history
```